# Накладывание кликов

Tags: jquery, события

Есть проблема с накладыванием кликов. При клике на сабмит на разных элементах - он суммируется. Вот пример:

```
var i = 1;
$('.item').toggle(function () {
        $('form').live('submit', function () {
            console.log(i);
            return false;
        });
    }, function () {
...
});
```

То есть кликуем на 1ую форму - 1 покажет 1 раз, на вторую форму покажет 2 раза, на третью 3 раза и т.п.
Но тут походу фишка из-за тугла, т.к. смотрел без него - все ок.

Comment: Вы из прошлого перенеслись к нам? )) Метод live() из новых версий библиотеки удален, метод toggle(), как привязка нескольких обработчиков - удален с версии 1.9

Расскажите, что вы хотите получить в итоге, разместите необходимый код на [jsfiddle.net][1]. Будем поглядеть...

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Возможно есть решение этой проблемы, т.к. перейти на свежую версию на получится.

Comment: Есть решение - оставайтесь на древней версии. Но как бы там ни было, для решения вашей задачи - выкладывайте код на fiddle и опишите по-человечески суть этой задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас при каждом клике (ну или через раз, что во второй функции мы не видим) вешается новый обработчик live. Два раза повесили, будет два обработчика и они оба сработают...

Зачем вам нужен toogle не совсем понятно, но точно одно назначение обработчиков должно происходить только один раз, которого вполне достаточно. Уберите его из toggle. И да, расскажите какого результата вы пытаетесь добиться с toggle&live.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает нормально. Фишка в том, что на странице несколько форм, которые подгружаются через аякс. Тугл нужен для подгрузки / скрытия формы. Данные подгружаются, то их легче обрабатывать через лайв. А засунул я его в тугл, чтобы было проще работать с элементами, некоторые данные атрибутов берутся от объекта созданного тугл функцией при первом срабатывание.

Comment: Сейчас же придется видимо передавать классу сначала объект созданный туглом, а уже после, когда сработает лайв событие - работать с объектом, который передал тугл. Но тут есть проблема - форм много и при открытых нескольких форм - будут неверные данные при работе с объектом в классе. Возможно есть метод "очистки" обработчика?

Comment: По вашему описанию, есть ощущение что вы делаете что-то не так, слишком сложная логика. Объект, если он создается в одном месте, а доступ к нему нужен дальше, можно поменстить в $(this).data('obj',obj). Впрочем, могут быть и другие варианты...

Comment: Да, спасибо, разобрался. Вопрос закрыт =)

Answer (score 0):

```
При клике на сабмит на разных элементах - он суммируется.
```

Мне кажется, что это связано со спецификой *live()*. Почему бы не использовать другой способ установки обработчика (заметил, кстати, что в вопросах установки обработчиков проявляют иногда излишнюю и неоправданную эктравагантность).